# python type error: data data type = 17 is not supported

Tags: opencv, python3

python3.6.1 opencv3

```py
flags=cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS
retval, bestLabels, codebook=cv2.kmeans(features,self.codebookSize,None,term_crit,iterMax,flags)
self.classifier.train(codebook,np.arry(range(self.codebookSize)))
```

```
codebook=cv2.kmeans(features,self.codebookSize,None,term_crit,iterMax,flags)
type error: data data type = 17 is not supported
```

cv2.kmeansのパラメータはあっている気がするのですが、どうやってエラーを回避すればよいのでしょうか、お教えいただければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV において `data type = 17` というのは、`CV_8SC3` 型である、つまり、符号付き 8bit char が3チャネルあることを表しています。

対して [`cv2.kmeans` のドキュメント](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html#ga9a34dc06c6ec9460e90860f15bcd2f88)によると、この関数の引数 `data` として許容されている行列要素の型は `CV_32F` か `CV_32FC2` のいずれかです。したがって、今回のプログラムだと変数 `features` の型をこのどちらかに合わせる必要があります。`features.shape` や `features.dtype` を用いて行列の形と要素の型を確認してみてください。

#### 参考

- データ型の番号と実際の型の対応表

  - [LIST OF MAT TYPE IN OPENCV](http://ninghang.blogspot.jp/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html) -- Vision Life
  - [A raw Mat::type in a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39780825/5989200) -- 本家 Stack Overflow における [empty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1637126/empty) さんの投稿
- [`cv::kmeans` のドキュメント](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d5/d38/group__core__cluster.html#ga9a34dc06c6ec9460e90860f15bcd2f88) -- OpenCV 3.2.0